# Count the number of hat tricks i.e 3 wins in a row (1 - win, 0-loss)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Count the number of hat tricks from the result. i.e., 3 wins in a row (Here `Result` 1 for win, 0 for loss)

```
MatchNo     Match_date  Name    Result
--------------------------------------
1           2015-04-08  Aditya  1
2           2015-04-09  Aditya  0
3           2015-04-10  Aditya  0
4           2015-04-11  Aditya  0
5           2015-04-11  Aditya  0
6           2015-04-12  Aditya  0
7           2015-04-12  Aditya  1
8           2015-04-13  Aditya  1
9           2015-04-14  Aditya  0
10          2015-04-15  Aditya  1
11          2015-04-16  Aditya  0
12          2015-04-17  Aditya  0
13          2015-04-18  Aditya  0
14          2015-04-18  Aditya  0
15          2015-04-19  Aditya  1
16          2015-04-19  Aditya  1
17          2015-04-20  Aditya  1
18          2015-04-21  Aditya  1
19          2015-04-22  Aditya  1
20          2015-04-22  Aditya  0
21          2015-04-23  Aditya  0
```

Comment: When streak = 1 does that indicate its a hatrick?

Comment: 1 means win and 0 means loss, actually streak here as result

Comment: And how do you define a hat-trick? What's the expected output (with the sample input as given.)

Comment: @ddsprasad So what is the definition of hatrick in your data?

Comment: if a person is winning in a row as match 1,2,3 then it counted as 1 hatrick, if he wins 1,2,3,4 in a row loss the next one then also it is counted as 1 hattrick. hope this give you idea

Comment: So a 1 hatrick is 3 streaks of wins

Comment: @ChristianBarron: actually i tried to slef join and applied conditions based on match_date. and tried to cross apply

Comment: Again, what's the expected result when having your sample data as input - please edit the question. Also add other info from your comments, like what 1/0 means!

Comment: Can you add the sql you've tried and the expected output onto the question then please?

Comment: @jarlh my excepted result is count of hattrick wins by person , if he wins 3 in a row [ 1=win,0=loss] then it will be counted as 1 for aditya here

Comment: That's not the expected result, that's an explanation... Can't you help us to help you?!?

Comment: here the result should be : Name - aditya , No_Hatricks - 1

Comment: So is it correct to state that a hattrick was achieved on each of these dates: `2015-04-20, 2015-04-21, 2015-04-22`? Or is that just one, as the whole streak can only count once?

Comment: Does 6 streak = 1 in a row mean 2 separate hat-tricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way without Cursors can be something like this. This considers 6 continuous streak as 2 hat-tricks. To consider it as a single streak we need to change the final `SUM(Streak)` to `COUNT(Streak)`

```
DECLARE @StreakTable Table (MatchNo int, Match_date date, Name varchar(20), Streak int)

Insert into @StreakTable values
(1, '2015-04-08', 'Aditya',1),
(2, '2015-04-09', 'Aditya',1),
(3, '2015-04-10', 'Aditya',0),
(4, '2015-04-11', 'Aditya',0),
(5, '2015-04-12', 'Aditya',1),
(6, '2015-04-13', 'Aditya',1),
(7, '2015-04-14', 'Aditya',1)

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT MatchNo,Match_date,Name,Streak,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Match_date) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name,streak ORDER BY Match_date)num
    FROM @StreakTable
), CountStreak as 
(
    SELECT Name,COUNT(*)/3 Streak
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Streak = 1
    GROUP BY num,Name
    HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 3
)
SELECT Name,SUM(Streak) as TotalStreak
FROM CountStreak
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 2):

As much as I hate cursors I can't think of another way to easily do this in SQL Server 2008 so you can try this:

```
Declare @count int = 0,
        @Streak int = 0,
        @Hattrick int = 0
Declare foobar cursor forward_only for Select Streak from Tablename

Open foobar

fetch next from foobar into @Streak

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    If @Streak = 1
        Set @count = @count + 1
    else
        Set @count = 0
    if @count = 3
        begin
           Set @Hattrick = @Hattrick + 1
           Set @count = 0
        end

    Fetch next from foobar into @Streak
End

Select @Hattrick
```

For later versions of SQL Server I would use a mixture of Cross Apply and Lag. Unfortunately Lag is only available in SQL Server 2014 onwards

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27273/4/0

For SQL Server 2014 use Cross Apply and LAG:

```
Select Sum(Hattrick) Hattricks

from

(Select Case when c.Streak = 1 and lag(c.Streak, 1,0) over (order by c.MatchNo) = 0 and lag(c.Streak, 2,0) over (order by c.MatchNo) = 0 then 1 else 0 end Hattrick

from @foobar f
Cross apply
(select case when f.Streak = 1 and Streak = 1 then 1 else 0 end Streak, MatchNo from @foobar where MatchNo = f.MatchNo - 1) b
Cross apply
(select case when b.Streak = 1 and Streak = 1 then 1 else 0 end Streak, MatchNo from @foobar where MatchNo = b.MatchNo - 1) c) Hat
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3a05/2/0

Comment: There is a non-cursor way but it involves self-joining the table 3 times (you basically check that previous 2 streaks are 1 and third-previous streak is 0 using a join on the "match" column) but cursors are probably neater here.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, the issue I had was it has to reset it's count after 3. So if you have 6 wins in a row it would only be 2 Hattricks (2x 3 consecutive wins). I done what you described and I struggled to get it to reset after the first set of 3 without using lag.

Comment: 6 wins in a row would still be 1 hat-trick though? That's why you need to condition on the third-previous being a 0.

Comment: No 6 wins in a row is 2 hat-tricks as a hat trick is 3 wins in a row so 6 wins in a row would be 2 x 3 wins = 2 hat-tricks or that's my understanding of the very ambiguous question

Comment: If 6 wins does count as 2 hat-tricks then this answer currently would only report 1 too, since it only counts when count = 3 but doesn't reset count.

Comment: nitpick: As a hat-trick is 3 wins in a row, would 6 wins in a row not constitute 4 hat-tricks? :) (1-3; 2-4, 3-5 and 4-6)

Comment: @Eterm you're right it didn't reset - I was testing you to see how observant you are ;) It resets now ha.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, no ha. I think it works in the traditional sense of a hat-trick UK - football, US - soccer where 3 consecutive goals by the same player = hat-trick but then it resets until there is another 3 consecutive goals

Comment: I think it is hard to find an unambigous definition, according to wiki it is not reset `A hat-trick or hat trick in sports is the achieving of a positive feat three times or more during a game—or, outside of sports, other achievements based on threes.`, but then according to this my interpretation could still be valid :D (but probably is not)

Comment: Haha maybe if the op question wasn't so ambiguous we'd actually know. If he brings some clarity then I will update accordingly.

Comment: 3 wins in a row considered as 1 hattrick, 6 in a row considered 2 hartticks, 5 in a row considered as 1 hattrick, 7 in a row considered as 2 hattricks, 8 in a row considered as 2 hartticks . hope you understand.

Comment: I have edited the question now , i changed streak  column to results , actually that is what made confusing i guess